# Can't run Docker command via ssh and python's subprocess module

Tags: docker, unix, amazon-ec2, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to automatically run a docker build command using the subprocess module as such:

```
command = "docker build -t image_name ."

ssh_command = "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i 'XXXXX.pem' ubuntu@" + cur_public_ip + " " + command

retval = subprocess.run(command.split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

if retval.stderr != '':
    print('Error trace: ')
    print(retval.stderr)
else:
    print("Docker image succesfully built.")
    print(retval.stdout)
```

Interestingly, if I run this command (the string that is the command variable) after I manually SSH into my ec2 instance, it works fine.

But when I run the code above, I get this error:

```
Error trace: 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I can't seem to solve this problem, and I am stuck since I don't see how what I am doing is different from manually sshing into the instance and running the command.

The docker daemon is definitely running since I can build manually through an ssh terminal. I've tried changing the rwx permissions of the Dockerfile and all related files on the ec2 instance, but that did not help as well.

How do I make this work? I need to programmatically be able to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: For an alternate path, consider using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of shelling out to `docker` commands, and setting the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to `ssh://ubuntu@cur_public_ip` to tell it to use an ssh transport to connect to the remote Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're only passing `command` to `subprocess.run`, so you're running `docker build` locally:

```
                        +--- look here
                        |
                        v
retval = subprocess.run(command.split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Your second problem is that you've got way to much quoting going on in `ssh_command`, which is going to result in a number of problems. As written, for example, you'll be passing the *literal* string `'StrictHostKeyChecking=no'` to `ssh`, resulting in an error like:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: 'stricthostkeychecking
```

Because you're not executing your command via a shell, all of those quotes will be passed literally in the command line.

Rather than calling `command.split(" ")`, you would be better off just building the command as a list, something like this:

```py
import subprocess

cur_public_ip = "1.2.3.4"
command = ["docker", "build", "-t", "image_name", "."]

ssh_command = [
    "ssh",
    "-o",
    "stricthostkeychecking=no",
    "-i",
    "XXXXX.pem",
    f"ubuntu@{cur_public_ip}",
] + command

retval = subprocess.run(
    ssh_command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
```

Comment: Wonderful. I've been staring at a larger script containing this snippet for far too long. Silly me. Thank you good sir